# How do I use array reduce to sum object property lengths w/o typeof

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects each containing an array of other objects. I would like to use reduce to sum the lengths of all of these arrays. To do this I seem to have to provide a `typeof` check first like this...

```
var totalTasks = $scope.list.reduce(function(a, b){
  var aNum = 0, bNum = 0;
  if(typeof a === "object" && a.subItems){
      aNum = a.subItems.length
  }
  else{
      aNum = a
  }
  if(b.subItems) {
      bNum = b.subItems.length;
  }
  return aNum + bNum;
});
```

It seems like there has to be a way to do this without the typeof. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use  a start value and a check if `a.subItems` is an array?

```
var totalTasks = $scope.list.reduce(function(r, a){
    if ('subItems' in a && Array.isArray(a.subItems) {
        return r + a.subItems.length;
    }
    return r;
}, 0);
```

Comment: That bracket seems misplaced

Comment: i am helpless without ide.

Comment: This Seems like essentially the same still will throw undefined exception if subitems is null

Comment: Also I think the fails because the first time r is the array. I will create a plunker that shows this

Comment: Nm missed the context at the end

Comment: @Jackie, maybe the added check will help.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is to provide an initial value for the accumulator:

```
var totalTasks = $scope.list.reduce(function(num, el) {
  return num + el.subItems.length;
}, 0);
// ^
```

Here you can be sure that `num` is always a number. If you need to check whether `el` actually exists and contains `subItems`, you can add that of course (`num + (el && el.subItems && el.subItems.length || 0)`).

Comment: What if subitems is null? Won't it throw an exception?

Comment: If you can provide a plnkr I can confirm now otherwise I have to create one.

Comment: @Jackie: You said in your question that each object in the array would contain `subItems`, so I thought the check is not necessary. If `subItems` can be `null`, you can use the expression from my last paragraph.